# Solving a complex equation.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\gamma : [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb C$ be defined as $\gamma(t)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}+e^{it}$. Then the image of $\gamma$ is a circle centered at $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}$ and of radius $1$. This circle passes through $0$, and I want to find $t_0 \in [0, 2\pi]$ such that $\gamma(t_0)=0$. So, I want to solve the equation $\gamma(t)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}+e^{it}=0$, and I get $t = \frac{1} {i} \text{Log} \left( \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)= \text{Arg} \left( \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)-i$, but this $t$ is not real, so it's not in $[0, 2\pi]$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\gamma(t)=0\iff e^{\pi i/6} +e^{it}=0\iff e^{it}=-e^{\pi/6}=e^{7\pi i/6}\iff t=\frac{7\pi}6$$

keeping in mind that we have chosen a specific value for the angle and etc.

Comment: How did you get $\pi/6$?

Comment: @Twink :$$e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t=\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac12i\implies t=\frac{\pi i}2$$

Comment: In the above it must be $\;t=\frac{\pi }6\;$ , of course

Comment: So, I have to solve either $t=\arccos \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or $t = \arcsin \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: It's just that now I'm trying to do the same with $\gamma(t)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}+e^{-it}$ but I get $t=\arccos \left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) = \frac{5\pi}{6}$ and $t= \arcsin \left(- \frac{1}{2} \right) = - \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: @Twink, calculators don't distinguish between $\;\frac{-\frac12}{\frac{\sqrt3}2}\;$ and $\;\frac{\frac12}{-\frac{\sqrt3}2}\;$ , and thus we *must* distinguish. Since $$\frac{\sqrt3}2-\frac12i=e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t\implies \cos t=\frac{\sqrt3}2>0\;,\;\;\sin t=-\frac12<0\;$$ and thus we're in the fourth quadrant of the trigonometric circle, and the correct angle is either $\;t\in\left(\frac{3\pi}2\,,\,\,2\pi\right)\;$ , or else $\;t\in\left(-\frac\pi2\,,\,\,0\right)\;$ , so the correct angle in our case is the second one, $\;-\frac\pi6\;$ .

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

$\gamma(t_0) = 0$ if $\displaystyle e^{it} = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{i}{2} = e^{(7\pi /6 + 2k\pi)i}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence ...